# save a table from ms word in image format?

Tags: c#, ms-word

I'm generating a table in word document, due to some alignment issues i want to save that table in my system in image format, is there anyway to save that table from word document?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using the Windows API Clipboard functions.  See `GetClipboardData()`.

So it can be done in C# referencing the clipboard API.

Also check http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/2207/Clipboard-handling-with-NET, which uses the `System.Windows.ClipBoard` class, a thin wrapper on the Windows API.